# jQuery to remove duplicate elements from list by value

Tags: jquery

I am trying to remove li elements which have duplicate values.

I have a list as shown below:

```
<ul>
  <li value="1" name="moon" id="moon1">Moon<li>
  <li value="2" name="moon" id="moon2">Moon<li>
  <li value="1" name="moon" id="moon3">Moon<li>
  <li value="3" name="moon" id="moon4">Moon<li>
  <li value="4" name="moon" id="sun1">Sun<li>
  <li value="5" name="moon" id="sun2">Sun<li>
  <li value="4" name="moon" id="sun3">Sun<li>
</ul>
```

I need something like this:

```
<ul>
  <li value="1" name="moon" id="moon1">Moon<li>
  <li value="2" name="moon" id="moon2">Moon<li>
  <li value="3" name="moon" id="moon4">Moon<li>
  <li value="4" name="moon" id="sun1">Sun<li>
  <li value="5" name="moon" id="sun2">Sun<li>
</ul>
```

I am very basic to jQuery.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: Side note: `name` is an invalid attribute for [`li` elements](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-li-element). Consider using a [`data-*` attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes) instead. (And be sure you're using `value` correctly, it has [a very different meaning for `li`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#ordinal-value) than for other elements.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `name` is invalid attribute for `<li>` element. Need to use [data-* attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2A-attributes)
2. `li` need to be closed with `</li>` (which is not happening in your HTML so correct it)
3. Iterate over each `li`,compare values and remove duplicates

Working code snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var found = {};
  $('li').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if(found[$this.attr('value')]){
      $this.remove();
    }else{
      found[$this.attr('value')] = true;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li value="1" data-name="moon" id="moon1">Moon</li>
  <li value="2" data-name="moon" id="moon2">Moon</li>
  <li value="1" data-name="moon" id="moon3">Moon</li>
  <li value="3" data-name="moon" id="moon4">Moon</li>
  <li value="4" data-name="moon" id="sun1">Sun</li>
  <li value="5" data-name="moon" id="sun2">Sun</li>
  <li value="4" data-name="moon" id="sun3">Sun</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this.

Working fiddle: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rynwbau4/1/)

```
var seen = {};

$('.list li').each(function() {
  var txt = $(this).text();

  if (seen.hasOwnProperty(txt)) {
    $(this).closest("li").remove();
  } else {
    seen[txt] = true;
  }
});
```

and html like

```
<ul>
  <li value="1" name="moon" id="moon1">Moon<li>
  <li value="2" name="moon" id="moon2">Moon<li>
  <li value="1" name="moon" id="moon3">Moon<li>
  <li value="3" name="moon" id="moon4">Moon<li>
  <li value="4" name="moon" id="sun1">Sun<li>
  <li value="5" name="moon" id="sun2">Sun<li>
  <li value="4" name="moon" id="sun3">Sun<li>
 <ul>
```